# What open-source materials are available for understanding basic designs for bookshelves / cabinetry?

Tags: construction, custom-cabinetry

I'd like to build a fairly large (11' x 7') set of built-in bookcases with lower doors, and am trying to understand the critical components and construction steps.

I'd like to find freely available materials with good instructions that cover bases such as the basic construction, suggested stock to use, building basic doors, adding finishing touches, and finishing the piece.

Comment: The [Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com/) site in the [StackExchage](http://stackexchange.com) family, is fairly useful. You could ask questions about each step of the building process, and even ask additional questions if you get stuck along the way.